# SwaggerUI base path IIS

Tags: swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore, asp.net-core-6.0

I have swagger UI defined as follows in my netcore 6 app

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(x =>
        {              
            var descriptions = apiVersionDescriptionProvider.ApiVersionDescriptions.OrderByDescending(x => x.ApiVersion.MajorVersion).ThenByDescending(x => x.ApiVersion.MinorVersion).ToList();
            var defaultDescription = descriptions.Where(x => x.ApiVersion == defaultApiVersion).SingleOrDefault();
            descriptions.Remove(defaultDescription);
            descriptions.Insert(0, defaultDescription);

            foreach (var description in descriptions)
                x.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant() + (description.ApiVersion == defaultApiVersion ? " (current)" : ""));

            x.DefaultModelsExpandDepth(-1);
            x.InjectStylesheet("/swagger-ui/custom.min.css");
            x.InjectJavascript("/swagger-ui/custom.js");
        });
```

This works fine and peachy on dev machine. On the server, I have to put my app in `{iisroot}/eea/corat` folder. All the swagger URLs are broken as they reference straight from `{issroot}`

So I tried adding
`x.RoutePrefix = "eea/corat/";` right above `var descriptions =`

This however makes my application not even run in dev. The application opens to a white screen and crashes in a few seconds.

How do I tell swagger UI about my prefix correctly?

Comment: Does browser console shows any error? Have you install the [.Net core hosting bundle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0)? Could you please inform us where did you configure the above settings? Make sure the path you mentioned for swagger.json is correct. Are you getting any popup like 'swagger UI is not able to find the swagger.json file.'? Try to add `.` or `..` in the path `/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json` See whether it make any difference.

Comment: `..` worked on IIS. Though that doesn't really answer the question why actually setting the prefix crashes the system...

Comment: For testing purposes, you could try to set the prefix like this sample code. See whether it works. `c.SwaggerEndpoint("/SampleApi/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Sample API"); c.RoutePrefix = "SampleApi/swagger";`